# Compact way of simulating 'axes' parameter in scipy.signal.fftconvolve?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

[scipy.signal.fftconvolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html) doesn't seem to have an `axes` parameter like for example [numpy.fft.fftn](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftn.html), meaning out of the box it will convolve along *all* axes.

I'm looking for the most painless way to have it only convolve along a given subset of axes. Does anyone know a workaround or shortcut?

Comment: It's an [open issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3525)... The alternatives appear to be: (1) call fftconvolve in a loop, passing to it the slices that you want to be transformed, one by one; (2) copy the source of fftconvolve ([pretty short](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.1/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L246-L378)) and add axes parameter, then passing it to fftn; (3)  write a PR to SciPy addressing the issue...

Comment: Thanks! Not quite as painless as I had hoped, but (2) looks ok-ish.